# Data from wtform doesn't write to the DB - Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm trying to create a simple table (ID, Name) with three routes - home, add, view. Add will add a name to the table and view will show the full table.
The full code pushed here so it will be easier to just run it with Docker: https://github.com/Nadavbm/Python/tree/master/flask/sql/name

For some reason I cannot write data to the db from this route\view:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    form = NameForm()
    print('Name form created')
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        print('Post entered and form validated')
        named = Name(name=form.name.data)
        try:
            print('Trying to add new name to db')
            db.session.add(named)
            print('Add name')
            db.session.commit()
            print('Commit name')
            flash('Added name successfully!')
        except  e:
            print('Exception!!')
            session.rollback()
            print(e)
        return redirect(url_for('view'))
    return render_template('add.html', form=form)
```

As you can see in the full code I use Jinja2 in html, forms.py, models.py - but I cannot find the reason for it not to write to the DB and not to have any error as well...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `form.validate()` is always False because `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` is commented out in the form template.